# Visual studio for Mac looks into different class than referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-mac

After accidentally hitting rename of my skv_match class to skv_player class I have issue with my ReadMatches method. The Visual studio keeps telling me, there is no definition of methods in class skv_player when I use class skv_match instead (after I renamed the class back to skv_match).

I am desperate and don't know if I am doing something wrong or Visual studio for Mac is. Does anybody know how to solve this or did I miss something in the code?

I tried to restart the app and laptop, rebuild and clean project. I also tried deleting the figuring classes, creating them again and pasting the original content in them.

```
public string ReadMatches()
        {
            var matches = _context.skv_match.AsNoTracking();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (matches == null)
            {
                return "No matches found";
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var skv_match in matches)
                {
                    sb.Append($"Match id: {skv_match.id }\r\n");
                    sb.Append($"Match results: {skv_match.home_team}");
                    sb.Append($"{skv_match.home_score }:");
                    sb.Append($"{skv_match.visitor_score } ");
                    sb.Append($" {skv_match.visitor_team }\r\n");
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }


public class skv_match
    {
        [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string home_team { get; set; }
        public string visitor_team { get; set; }
        public int home_score { get; set; }
        public int visitor_score { get; set; }
    }
```

I get error: "'skv_player' does not contain a definition for 'home_team' and no accessible extension method 'home_team' accepting a first argument of type 'skv_player' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" and same for other methods

I expect the app to just take this without any errors, yet I get error that class I am not referencing misses methods. Before I accidentally hit rename the class everything worked just fine.

Comment: Try changing the `foreach` loop variable (i.e. `foreach(var match in matches)`).  Maybe a name conflict since the variable is the same name as the class?

Comment: @eye_am_groot good idea, sadly doesn't work :(

Comment: Not sure if VS for Mac is the same, but try deleting the `bin` folder then rebuild.

Comment: @penleychan just tried it and sadly it doesnt, I also tried to delete cache in obj folder

Answer (score 0):

Ok my apologies to everyone who took time trying to help me. There was issue in Entity framework DbContext. I don't know if I was just tiredly stupid, or mentioned missclick changed it.

For anyone trying to solve this issue, try Right click on the declaration and "Go to declaration". It will point you to the part where you define it. 
To be specific, I clicked on part skv_match at var matches = _context.skv_match.AsNoTracking();